# How to add a plot line on a CSS Chart

Tags: html, css, charts, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to add a horizontal line at a set point using [chartscss.org](https://chartscss.org/)

For example, on the chart below using Charts CSS, I'm trying to add a horizonal line at the 15.5.. Similar to the image below.

I've tried a few different things such as making the chart `position: relative` and adding an absolute over the chart but not sure how to get it to be exactly at `15.5` given the chart / values.

```css
tbody {
  min-height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/charts.css/dist/charts.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="charts-css column show-labels data-spacing-10" id="my-chart">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Stat</th>
      <th scope="col">Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody class="position-relative mb-4">
    <tr>
      <th>1/14</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.48; --color: #bc2e2f">12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1/15</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.84; --color: #27ae60">21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1/19</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.64; --color: #27ae60">16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1/24</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.48; --color: #bc2e2f">12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1/27</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.64; --color: #27ae60">16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1/29</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.64; --color: #27ae60">16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1/31</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.56; --color: #bc2e2f">14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2/4</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.96; --color: #27ae60">24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2/5</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.52; --color: #bc2e2f">13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2/7</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.56; --color: #bc2e2f">14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2/9</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.4; --color: #bc2e2f">10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2/11</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.68; --color: #27ae60">17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2/12</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.72; --color: #27ae60">18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2/16</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.68; --color: #27ae60">17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2/24</th>
      <td style="--size: 1; --color: #27ae60">25</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this is what you want?

```css
:root {
  --value-scale: calc(450px / 25);
}

tbody {
  min-height: 450px;
  position: relative;
}

tbody::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(var(--value-scale) * 15.5 + 1px);
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid blue;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/charts.css/dist/charts.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table class="charts-css column show-labels data-spacing-10" id="my-chart">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Stat</th>
      <th scope="col">Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody class="position-relative mb-4">
    <tr>
      <th>1/14</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.48; --color: #bc2e2f">12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1/15</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.84; --color: #27ae60">21</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1/19</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.64; --color: #27ae60">16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1/24</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.48; --color: #bc2e2f">12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1/27</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.64; --color: #27ae60">16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1/29</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.64; --color: #27ae60">16</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>1/31</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.56; --color: #bc2e2f">14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2/4</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.96; --color: #27ae60">24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2/5</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.52; --color: #bc2e2f">13</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2/7</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.56; --color: #bc2e2f">14</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2/9</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.4; --color: #bc2e2f">10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2/11</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.68; --color: #27ae60">17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2/12</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.72; --color: #27ae60">18</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2/16</th>
      <td style="--size: 0.68; --color: #27ae60">17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>2/24</th>
      <td style="--size: 1; --color: #27ae60">25</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: yeah close, although looks like that line wouldn't be at 15.5, also I should've put this in the OP, but this value will change and not always be 15.5 or based on the example data.. so I'm not sure how to do that dynamically with CSS only

Comment: I think you should include JS as well, I'm not sure if it's possible to do it dynamically with CSS only